# declares the selector presentviewcontroller

Tags: ios, interface, animated, presentviewcontroller

Hello I have a little problem.

I got an application for a project, but it is a somewhat old application (IOS 7).

I saw on the internet how to update the UIAlertController Using INSTEAD of good-old UIAlertView.

```
if (error.code) {
cancelBlock = block;


UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: @"Message"
                                                                    message: @"Peripheral Disconnected with Error"
                                                             preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction *alertAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"OK"
                                                      style: UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                                    handler: ^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                        NSLog(@"OK");
                                                    }];

[alert addAction: alertAction];

[self presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];







/*  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Peripheral Disconnected with Error"
                                                    message:error.description
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];*/
```

I get an error that I do not understand:

No visible @interface for 'RFduino' declared the selector 'presentViewController: animated: completion'

Comment: what is RFduino for you in project

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of using this:

```
[self presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
```

Try this:

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
if ( viewController.presentedViewController && !viewController.presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed ) {
    viewController = viewController.presentedViewController;
}

NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint 
    constraintWithItem:alert.view 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual 
    toItem:nil 
    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
    multiplier:1 
    constant:viewController.view.frame.size.height*2.0f];

[alert.view addConstraint:constraint];
[viewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: @Dh1_Bh1 -- sorry bro I am not worked in this scenario before

Comment: Thank you @Anbu.Karthik, your answer solved my problem. +1 Upvote :)

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'alert'

Answer (score 2):

`presentViewController: animated: completion:` is a method of `UIViewController`. The class where you have made a call to this method, is that a subclass of `UIViewController`?